# How can I manipulate 4 Panel in one form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 4 panels each of one has their own `TextBox`es, `Button`s, and `DataGridView`. My problem is only *two* panels are showing the other is none. When I click the *1st* `Button` I want to show the `panel1` and hide the other panels. And when I click the *2nd* `Button` I want to *hide* the `panel1` and the other panel. How can I do it? Can somebody help me with my problem? It this possible to happen?

```
private void btnItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pnlItems.Visible != true)
    {
        pnlItems.Visible = true;
        pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
        pnlPOS.Visible = false;
        pnlDelivery.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void btnCustomers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pnlCustomer.Visible != true)
    {
        pnlCustomer.Visible = true;
        pnlItems.Visible = false;
        pnlPOS.Visible = false;
        pnlDelivery.Visible = false;
    }

}

private void btnPOS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pnlPOS.Visible != true)
    {
        pnlPOS.Visible = true;
        pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
        pnlItems.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void btnDelivery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pnlDelivery.Visible != true)
    {
        pnlDelivery.Visible = true;
        pnlPOS.Visible = false;
        pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
        pnlItems.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlItems.Visible = true;
    pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
    pnlPOS.Visible = false;
    pnlDelivery.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you didn't __accidentally nest__ some of them!!

Comment: What should I do if I ever do that?

Comment: You forgot to set `pnlDelivery.Visible = false;` in `btnPOS_Click`. @DmitryBychenko's solution removes a lot of resembling, almost duplicate code, making it less likely to forget something.

Comment: Move it off the other panel carefully. place them apart and use code to move them to their final place. We don't see the desired layout, so maybe this is not your issue at all. test by printing out each panel's Parent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's *extract a method*:

```
 private void MakePanelVisisble(Panel panel) {
   Panel[] panels = new Panel[] {
     pnlItems, pnlCustomer, pnlPOS, pnlDelivery,
   }; 

   foreach (var p in panels)
     p.Visible = (p == panel);
 }
```

Then

```
 private void btnItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   MakePanelVisisble(pnlItems); 
 }

 private void btnCustomers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   MakePanelVisisble(pnlCustomer); 
 }

 ...

 private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   MakePanelVisisble(pnlItems);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Give your Panels Tags 1,2,3,4;

the write a method like this:

```
private void ShowPanel(int id)
{
    var panels = myform.Controls.OfType<Panel>();
    foreach(Panel p in panels)
        p.Visible = (int)p.Tag == id)
}
```

Then in your buttons use it like:

```
private void btnPOS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ShowPanel(2);
}
```